# Strange deduction about relation of median and mean

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, integral-inequality

On his blog T. Tao's proves the following concentration inequality, due to Talagrand.

Let $K>0$, and let $X_{1},..., X_{n}$ be iid complex random variables all bounded by $K$. Let $F:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $1$-Lipshitz convex function (for this identify $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ ). Then for any $\lambda$ one has:
$$ \mathbb{P}(|F(X)-MF(X)|\geq\lambda K)\leq C \exp(-c\lambda ^{2})  \tag{1}$$
and
$$ \mathbb{P}(|F(X)-\mathbb{E}F(X)|\geq\lambda K)\leq C \exp(-c\lambda ^{2})  \tag{2}.$$

He claims that it is sufficient to prove  $(1)$, because $(1)$ imples in turn that:
$$\mathbb{E}F(X)=MF(X)+\mathcal{O}(1)$$
which then gives $(2)$.

WHY IS $$\mathbb{E}F(X)=MF(X)+\mathcal{O}(1)$$ true, and in particular why can it be deduced from $(1)$?

Comment: can you give a link to his blog post?

Comment: http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf at the top of page 87.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m$ denote the median. By the triangle inequality $\bigl|\Bbb E F(X)-m\bigr|\leq \Bbb E(|F(X)-m|)$. But this expectation is
$$
 E(|F(X)-m|) = \int_0^\infty \Bbb P(|F(X) - m| \geq \lambda)\,d\lambda \leq KC\int_0^\infty e^{-c\lambda^2}\,d\lambda = O(1).
$$

Answer (score 4):

For every nonnegative random variable $Y$,
$$
E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P[Y\geqslant y]\,\mathrm dy.
$$
Applying this to $Y=|F(X)-MF(X)|$ and using (1), one gets
$$
E[|F(X)-MF(X)|]\leqslant\int_0^\infty C\mathrm e^{-cy^2/K^2}\,\mathrm dy=CK/\sqrt{c}\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-y^2}\mathrm dy.
$$
Thus, $E[F(X)]=MF(X)+R(X)$, where $|R(X)|\leqslant CK\sqrt{\pi/(4c)}$.

Comment: I accepted Ju's answer, because he was the first... But your answer is equally helpful. Thanks.